# Atom Electron does not load local storage

Tags: storage, electron, atom-editor

I'm using electron to build a desktop application and needs to store data.
In the browser script I write

```
if localStorage.getItem("now") == null
    localStorage.setItem("now", Date())
```

But this piece of code always get `null` for `localStorage.getItem` after page reload or electron application restart. The `now` value is always rewritten.

Disable Cache in the Network panel is not checked.

I've checked that localStorage has been written to local file `/Users/user/Library/Application Support/app/Local Storage/file__0.localstorage`. It appears the browser not load that file and will overwrite it on exist.

Change userData path to application directory does not help with this problem either.

I'm using electron 0.34.0 on OSX 10.11

Does someone have any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your app crashes when quitting or you use other ways like `process.exit` instead of `app.quit` to quit. If so, the `localStorage` will not be persisted by electron.